# Floodfill: Stack vs. Queue

Tags: algorithm, time, stack, queue, flood-fill

It is possible to write a flood fill function that uses either a queue or a stack. Which is faster under which circumstances (if at all), and why?

Comment: I think no one is faster. But using queue **might** reach the target node first, if it is near the start node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided you implement them correctly they should be equally fast. That is avoid recursion, implement the queue using a vector, not a linked list.

Both have O(N) complexity (N is the number of cells to be filled).

For very large examples(I would guess 10k x 10k), you might implement the stack approach so that you favor memory cache lines which would give you a slight advantage. This is hard to do right, reliably, since it is hardware dependent.